# Creating a new DOM Element with multiple elements inside and attach to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given this element:

```
<div class="box" id="trololo">
     <h2 class="header gradient-red"></h2>
     <div class="body">
          <div class="queue">
               <ul class="queue-list">

               </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="time">

          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Which is a skeleton, I would like to insert it in the DOM, hidden and animate it's entry. I really love this way, because it's elegant:

```
jQuery('</div>',{
    id: 'trololo',
    class: 'box'
}).hide().appendTo('#anotherDiv').fadeIn('slow');
```

But, how could I chain multiple elements like this?

I've thought about adding the whole html in the `html` property but doesn't sound fine for me.

Comment: To clarify: are you looking for a neat way to create DOM tree as shown above, or are you trying to insert several sibling nodes to a div?

Comment: I want to create the given DOM tree (or whatever) in a neat way

Comment: You can't just place it inside the HTML source code and hide it with CSS?

Comment: I suggest templating. That way you don't have to embed lots of html in your javascript code, which is out of place. Although if your examples are small (I don't consider this to be small), then you can use native jquery methods to build the tree.

Comment: @davin thanks for your appreciation but this is a pannel where I would see people logging in and out in a system. How could I add templating in such scenario?

Comment: @AntonioLaguna Templating is used when a certain DOM structure has to be created repeatedly. Is that your case? Do you need that structure multiple times? If you only need it once, then just put it in the HTML source code and hide it with CSS...

Comment: Yes, I think I would need to use Templating, where to start? @ŠimeVidas

Comment: @AntonioLaguna Well, there is the [jquery-tmpl plugin](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) but its development is currently halted. One alternative would be [JsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender)...

Comment: @AntonioLaguna try mustachejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/TazCV/1/)

```
$("<div>", {
    className: 'box',
    id: 'trololo'
}).append(
    $('<h2>', {
        className: 'header gradient-red'
    }),
    $('<div>', {
        className: 'body'  
    }).append(
        $('<div>', {
            className: 'queue' 
        }).append(
            $('<ul>', {
                className: 'queue-list',
                textContent: 'dummy-text' 
            })  
        ),
        $('<div>', { 
            className: 'time' 
        }) 
    )
).hide().appendTo('#anotherDiv').fadeIn('slow');
```

Whether this is the 'readability' you were looking for is for you to decide.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you add the html fragment (hidden) to the base html document and simply call .fadeIn('slow') when you have to?

Comment: because that breaks progressive enhancement.

Comment: that depends on your the application itself. this certainly works. but maybe you can explain me where this breaks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement. Thanks.

Comment: Because your putting things into your html page that have no business being in the HTML. that HTML information in your page would never be displayed without javascript, it's just simply wrong

Comment: Very deterministic. It works and that counts. Sometimes you want to use icanhazjs, other times you do your own String.prototype.format and other times you keep elements in your html and extract them onload into variables like when you use <script id="XXX" type="text/html">.

Comment: script type='text/html' is far better then injecting hidden html into the page

Comment: it depends, if you need to serve to i.e. many corporate blackberry devices then its wise to leave your fingers away from it since it may confuse the poor browser, embedding html fragments into a hidden part of the page on the other hand is fine. thats why I meant it always depends on the context.